# SailsJS v0.1 + PassportJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I've used PassportJS within SailsJS v0.9.x and it worked flawlessly. Now updated to v0.1 and passportJS doesnt seem it work.

What I've done in http.js:

```
passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
```

And added passportInit to the middleware list.

I've defined my BasicStrategy like:

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(email, password, next) {
     // does not get called nor does it throw an error
  }
));
```

I'm calling this strategy with:

```
passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
  // ...
});
```

This does not return an error. It does return a nil user. Also when I remove this new BasicStrategy, it does throw an error that strategy Basic is not defined.

Anyone ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you're adding Passport to the middleware list in **config/http.js**?  Have you added it both to the `middleware` key and to the `order` array? (See the docs [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware?q=adding-or-overriding-http-middleware)).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue with SailsJS with PassportJS. I solved it by this way :-

```
someCtrl: function(req, res, next) {   
 passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
  // ...
})(req, res, next);
}
```